# Author affiliation and corresponding author for Springer journal

Tags: journal-publishing, sv-classes

I want to indicate the corresponding author in my manuscript planned to submit to a Springer journal (J. Signal Processing System), but I couldn't find any hints in the user manual.
Ideally, it should look like (This is the screenshot of one latest accepted publication)

[image: This is a screenshot of one latest accepted publication]

I tried to do it manually by making the following modification to the latex template linked with "svjour3.cls":

(1) add package `\usepackage[misc]{ifsym}` in order to use the envelope icon.

(2) define

```
\newcommand*{\affaddr}[1]{#1} 
\newcommand*{\affmark}[1][*]{\textsuperscript{#1}}
```

(3) Change the author and institute field:

```
\author{Author1 \protect\affmark[1]  \and
    Author2 \protect\affmark[1]   \and
    Author3 \protect\affmark[1]}
```

and

```
 \institute{
 \Letter $\;\;$  Author1 \\   \email{Author1@email.com}\\\\
 Author2 \\   \email{Author2@email.edu}\\\\
 Author3 \\   \email{Author3@email.com}\\\\
 \affaddr{\affmark[1]The Department of XXX at Latex University.}}
```

Then I got:

[image]

which is not exactly the same the above example (the remaining lines do not align with the envolope icon).

As pointing out in the comment, it seems like a ordinary footnote thing, but I still haven't been able to figure it out. Specifically, what the best or easiest way to

(1) numerate different institutes (the numeric superscript)?

(2) indicate the corresponding author this format?

[Here](https://www.overleaf.com/read/bcddccwpbpcg) is the overleaf link to my attempt.

Thank you all in advanced.

Comment: Please provide a MWE, tell what you tried, whether you have read any manual. Actually, to me it looks like ordinary footnotes, but I do not know the template.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've edited the question accordingly.

Comment: You should contact the publisher and ask how they handle things like that

Comment: Do you have any news for us? Is the issue solved? How?